# How to stop Debian Linux from throwing errors while running apt-get update

Tags: linux, http-status-code-404, apt-get

I am running Kali Linux. Recently I have tried to install wine I was unsuccessful when I run apt-get update I get this:

```
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org vivid Release.gpg
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org vivid Release                               
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org vivid/contrib amd64 Packages                
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg                 
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org vivid/contrib i386 Packages                 
Ign http://http.kali.org moto Release.gpg                                      
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates Release.gpg                          
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org vivid/contrib Translation-en                
Ign http://http.kali.org moto Release                                          
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates Release                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release.gpg                        
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/main Sources/DiffIndex                  
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main Sources/DiffIndex      
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/non-free Sources/DiffIndex              
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib Sources/DiffIndex   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release                            
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/contrib Sources/DiffIndex                        
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free Sources/DiffIndex  
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main amd64 Packages                         
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main i386 Packages                          
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                 
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex    
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release                     
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main i386 Packages          
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main Translation-en         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Translation-en                         
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/main i386 Packages                               
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free i386 Packages               
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/non-free i386 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib Translation-en               
Err http://http.kali.org moto/contrib i386 Packages                            
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main Translation-en                  
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/contrib Translation-en                           
Ign http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free Translation-en              
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/main Translation-en                              
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main Sources                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib Sources                      
  404  Not Found
Ign http://http.kali.org moto/non-free Translation-en                          
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free Sources                     
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/main Sources                                     
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/main amd64 Packages                  
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/non-free Sources                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/contrib amd64 Packages               
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/contrib Sources                                  
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.kali.org moto/updates/non-free amd64 Packages              
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/main amd64 Packages                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/non-free amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Err http://http.kali.org moto/contrib amd64 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/non-free/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/dists/moto/updates/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I no longer want to install wine!! the how can I stop remove these 404 errors. I preferably want to somehow remove them from the list of things to be updated .. And also in a semi related topic what does it mean by you have held broken packages? I

Comment: Are you sure your problem comes from wine installation ? Because the 404 errors point on kali or security kali which are packets that are nothing to do with wine...

Comment: No, I am not certain but the binary-i386 files I believe were a dependencie that was required to run wine. This problem didn't start until I tried to install wine. I want it to stop trying to update all this stuff all together..

Comment: What did you find on the internrt?

Comment: I have edited my comment and cut & paste the missing part inside the underneath answer because I think this is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem does not come from Wine installation but from your OS. Apparently Kali expects its users to upgrade to Kali Moto (2.0). You can found this information here : http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/fix-my-kali-update-configuration-0165497/

According to Kali's website:

*We've given Kali Moto (1.0) a good two months of grace time and will be purging the unsupported 1.0 distribution files from our repositories in the next few days. If you're still using Kali 1.0 then it's definitely time to either upgrade or update.
https://www.kali.org/news/kali-moto-eol/
Basically, they're forcing the update\upgrade to 2.0.*

Comment: @Dezmyn Beatty, You're welcome ! If my answer resolves your problem, could you at least accept it ? Thanks